# Cubic spline memory error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

On a computer with 4GB of memory this simple interpolation leads to a memory error:

(based on: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 80000)
y = np.cos(-x**2/8.0)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
```

I thought about cutting the data into chunks, but is there a way I can perform this cubic spline interpolation without requiring so much memory?
Why does it even get in trouble?

Comment: I get a memory error on a computer with 16GB, so don't rush out and buy more memory to fix this. :)

Comment: Is this just a test case for a problem in which the actual function is less well-behaved?  Otherwise, you probably don't need 80000 points!  Even with 800 points, the worst case error between the interpolant and `np.cos(-x**2/8.0)` on the interval [0, 10] is less than 2e-8.

Comment: Yes, this was just a working example.

Comment: even with 32GB memory I get the error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the traceback when the error occurs, you'll see something like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1e538e8d766e> in <module>()
----> 1 f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

/home/warren/local_scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py in __init__(self, x, y, kind, axis, copy, bounds_error, fill_value)
    390         else:
    391             minval = order + 1
--> 392             self._spline = splmake(x, y, order=order)
    393             self._call = self.__class__._call_spline
    394 

/home/warren/local_scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py in splmake(xk, yk, order, kind, conds)
   1754 
   1755     # the constraint matrix
-> 1756     B = _fitpack._bsplmat(order, xk)
   1757     coefs = func(xk, yk, order, conds, B)
   1758     return xk, coefs, order

MemoryError:
```

The function that is failing is `scipy.interpolate._fitpack._bsplmat(order, xk)`.  This function creates a 2-d array of 64-bit floats with shape `(len(xk), len(xk) + order - 1)`. In your case, this is over 51GB.

Instead of `interp1d`, see if [`InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html) works for you.  For example,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 80000)
y = np.cos(-x**2/8.0)
f2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=3)
```

I don't get a memory error with this.

Comment: Thank you for this suitable solution!

Comment: thanks, I think this should be used instead of the default which consumes too much memroy for something that requires memory for `order` last points